# Mapping radio options is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, radio-group

I am trying to map radio options to a table.

```
const [delayAllocation, setDelayAllocation] = React.useState('accept');
...

      <TBody>
          {data.map(({ code, decode, delay, delayOwner }, index: number) => (
            <Tr key={index}>
              <Td>{code}</Td>
              <Td>{decode}</Td>
              <Td>{addMinsPostfix(delay)}</Td>
              {delayOwner && delayResolver && ( //these conditions will show the radio options
                <Td>
                  <RadioOption
                    groupId="radioDelayAllocation"
                    label="Accept"
                    onChange={() => setDelayAllocation('accept')}
                    value={delayAllocation === 'accept'}
                  />
                  <RadioOption
                    groupId="radioDelayAllocation"
                    label="Reject"
                    onChange={() => setDelayAllocation('reject')}
                    value={delayAllocation === 'reject'}
                  />
                </Td>
              )}
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </TBody>
```

The output:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fd13.png)

```
O Accept * Reject
O Accept O Reject

* = selected, O = unselected
```

I can only select one out of the four radio options at a time; they seem to be grouped together as one radio option group where in fact it's 2 groups.

Desire output:

```
* Accept O Reject
* Accept O Reject

or 

O Accept * Reject
O Accept * Reject

or 

* Accept O Reject
O Accept * Reject

* = selected, O = unselected
```

The desire output would be to be able to separate the radio options and retrieve that state for that radio option group. I've already tried using the props id={index} for the Td and RadioOption tags, but no luck.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: What component library are you using? `RadioOption` appears to be from a library.

Comment: Hi Nick, the RadioOption component is from an internal library; it has the following props: label,
ariaActiveDescendant,  
ariaControls, 
ariaDescribedBy, 
ariaLabel,  
ariaLabelledBy, 
autoFocus,
disabled,
groupId, 
hideInput, 
id, 
invalid, 
onBlur () => void, 
onChange (value: boolean) => void,  
onFocus () => void,  
value

Comment: It would need some kind of `name` property that maps to the `<input name="..." />` field. Unless that's what `groupId` does. Can you post that component's code?

Comment: The code base is quite large, Maybe we dynamically render the props "groupId" to recognise to have 2 groups of RadioOption instead of 1.

Comment: My _guess_ is changing it to be `groupId={\`radioDelayAllocation-${index}\`}` might do it for you, if that's what populates the `name` atrribute of the underlying `input` elements.

Comment: That worked, the RadioOption were in 2 groups, thank you! Now the other problem I have is how would I keep a state for each RadioOption group? Current result I'm getting is both Accept or Reject is selected given that I only have one useState. For example, if I select Accept on one group, the other group will also select Accept.